# Apt_pkg seem to be missing in upgraded python

Tags: python, python3

I have upgraded my system python to 3.6 (3.6.10) from 3.5. My system is Ubuntu 16.04. For some reason I think that my python3.6 version has not been fully installed.
For example if I examined the folder where the cython is kept I cannot find the corresponding version of python3.6:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 70 May 12 14:14 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so -> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

except that 
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` does not exists!

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory
```

I have tried to install apt_pkg via:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-apt
```

but is does not seem to change anything.

So, my question is how do I install those cython libraries for the correct python version. By the way I can see the version of python3.5 in the folder:
`apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Edit (clarify the similar question's answers):
I have seen similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720578/modulenotfounderror-in-tracebacks-with-python3-6-on-linux) one on SO but the solutions proposed does not solve my issue. The 1st one that was supposed to install the library does not have any effect while the 2nd one seem to address the wrong symbolic link issue. In my case the library itself is missing though.

Comment: "I have upgraded my system python to 3.6 (3.6.10) from 3.5" How?

Comment: I used the ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 repository